# How can I use the strategic map to ease macro in CoH?

Tags: company-of-heroes

There is a nice strategic map popping up when hitting `NUM0` that displays all available units of your own as well as points of strategic relevance and discovered enemy troops. This is already nice from a tactical point of view, but I heard it is also possible to use this map to gain an advantage by making macro easier. How?